# A more efficient way to merge multiple objects together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to make an array that contains multiple objects, but first off I need to merge two kinds of objects into one, then add it to the array. The reason for this is so that I can loop through the array in a view and easily display the content. I'm working with tree different objects, Users, Players, and Teams. A User owns multiple players and multiple teams through players. I need to visually display information from both the team object and the player object, but I need to merge them into a single object and insert it into an array. So I'll be doing this for every team/player that the player owns and inserting them into an array that holds them all.

Here is my crack at this

```
    array = []
    @user.players.each do |player|
        @user.teams.each do |team|
            if player.team_id == team.id
                array << UserTeam.new(:id => team.id,
                                      :name => team.name,
                                      :tag => team.tag,
                                      :description => team.description,
                                      :recruiting => team.recruiting,
                                      :wins => team.wins,
                                      :losses => team.losses,
                                      :t_wins => team.t_wins,
                                      :rating => team.rating,
                                      :role => player.role,
                                      :position => player.position)
            end
        end
    end
    @teams = array
```

This works and I get the result I want, but I'm sure this is a really inefficient way to do it. What would be a better way of doing this? Can anyone help a rookie rails dev out?

Comment: What's the `UserTeam`? A join model of `User` and `Team`? Some non-AR class containing such fields? If the answer is the former, then does `UserTeam` contains all these attributes or they're just set via `attr_accessor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to determine why you're actually lumping everything into a single object. What are you intending to do with the result? If this is just for display purposes, you can use something much simpler and more elegant.

### Assumptions

#### Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :teams, through: :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
end
```

#### Controller

```
@players = @user.players.includes(:team)
```

#### View

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team Id</th>
      <th>Team Name</th>
      <!-- other team columns -->
      <th>Player Role</th>
      <th>Player Position</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @players.each do |player| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= player.team.id %></td>
      <td><%= player.team.name %></td>
      <!-- other columns -->
      <td><%= player.role %></td>
      <td><%= player.position %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```